# $location change not applied on ngchange but on ngclick

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have got 2 functions one is triggered by a ng-click and one is either triggered by ng-change or by $watch (I tried both).

The ng-click method looks like this:

```
$scope.setGenre = function(x) {
    if (genre == x) {
        genre = 0;
    } else {
        genre = x;
    }
    $location.search().genre = genre;
    $scope.getVideos();
};
```

When the button is clicked the genre parameter is set directly in the url to the value specified. I do not need to do $scope.$apply or something else.

The ng-change or $watch method looks actually the same:

```
$scope.$watch('search', function() {
    $location.search().search=$scope.search;
    $scope.getVideos();
});
```

But apparently the parameter is not set in the url. If I then run the ng-click function by doing a click the search parameter is set.

I tried wrapping the `$location.search().search=$scope.search;` in a $timeout or doing a $scope.apply but the problem is that the digest always running then.

Comment: Can you create a live demo (plunker /jsfiddle) of your issue?

Comment: Yes! Because I'm not seeing where `genre` is defined

More over, how did you expect it to work on URL: i.e what `original URL` is to turn into `refreshed URL`

There's also the `$locationChangeStart` and `$locationChangeSuccess` events to monitor `URL changes`

Comment: genre is defined above the function and actually the setGenre function works like I want it to. The second ($watch) function does not work like expected since it is the exact same code.

Comment: We need more infos to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) your problem. Do you think what you provided is enough?

Comment: yes I do but I will create a fiddle soon

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ehUGgiH8GqLlPhFn6H5h?p=preview
This is nearly all the code I got in the controller except that I removed the getVideos function. If I click on the button the $location.search().genre=genre; updates the parameter in the url but not if I do the same in the ng-change.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to simply use `$location.url()` instead of `$location.search()`. For me it is still not clear why `$location.search` does work differently when using ng-change or $watch.

This is my new function:

```
$scope.$watch('search', function() {
    $location.url('/videos?genre='+genre +"&search="+ $scope.search, false);
    $scope.getVideos();
});
```

In order to use the reloadOnSearch only when I want I edited the `$location.url()` function like this:

```
app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
    var original = $location.url;
    $location.url = function (url, reload) {
        if (reload === false) {
            var lastRoute = $route.current;
            var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                $route.current = lastRoute;
                un();
            });
        }
        return original.apply($location, [url]);
    };
}]);
```

This lets me pass a boolean parameter so that I can dynamically use reloadOnSearch or not.